# Am I in a sugar momma scam?

Tags: scams, sugar-daddy

Got followed and approached by a woman on Twitter. She says she is 37 and inherited money from her late husband. Red flags so far:

1. Says she is from Texas City, TX but living in Maryland, Twitter says she is from Michigan, and her phone extension is from Seattle Washington.
2. She called me stupid for asking for a picture of her holding a spoon to prove she is who she says she is.(even though all of her photos are of the same woman and i cant find them by reverse image searching it is still suspicious as her photos could be ripped from someone's Facebook
3. She said she isn't wanting anything sex wise but just wants to be happy by supporting others.
4. This is the biggest red flag for me. She said that she will write a check in my name and mobile deposit it to my bank. But she needs my online ID and password. When I said I didn't have the details for it on me she said "See you're not the one trying to help me here .. I don't need anything from you and seriously I'm trusting you with my money .. if we really have to do this then you have to trust me (scammers love talking about trust) when I say I got you.. I really do and seriously I don't need your info for anything .. I have the physical check with me and if I wanna make the deposit I need the username and password to sign in on the app to make the deposit. You can even take all your money out before sending me them to me .. mine is just to make your deposit and that's all" And that was the exact typing wording and format.

I haven't given her any information at all other than the state I'm from and what bank I use, but I am not giving any username or password unless I make a bank account to test the scammers waters, although I'm not sure I can open an account and then empty it so that's why I'm here looking for advice. Thank you so much for reading and commenting if you do. I will take all the info into consideration.

Comment: Not saying that it's not a scam (it is), but in these days of cell phones and portability, the area code of the phone number is no guide to where a person lives.  E.g. I have friends who've moved to different states & area code, but kept their phone numbers.

Comment: When did a spoon become a valid form of ID?

Comment: @JTP In case that's not just a joke: It helps verify that the other person is not using fake (a random person's) photos, if they can produce a photo with a requested pose/prop on demand. This, in turn, gives more confidence that the photos could be used to trace them if necessary.

Comment: It’s a scam. Cut off contact, block / delete and move on.

Comment: *but just wants to be happy by supporting others.*  She can support me by sending $2,000/day via Zelle.

Comment: *"I am not giving any username or password unless I make a bank account to test the scammers waters,"* **don't do this.**  A bank account in your name is a bank account in your name, regardless of why you open it. This could be something more involved than just stealing *your* money - like money laundering - and if/when the cops catch up to you, they are unlikely to be swayed by the idea that you were "just testing the scammers waters."

Answer (score 17):

Yes, it is a scam. No one needs your bank password to make a deposit.

Comment: But with your password, they can use your account to launder money and then when the incoming payments reverse themselves, you're on the hook.

Answer (score 3):

it’s a scam. she can text you the check image and you can deposit it electronically. or she can mail you the check. or she can Zelle transfer you the money via phone number or email these days!